# how to draw route in MapView

Tags: iphone-sdk-4.1

Is it possible to draw route in MKMapView.
 I want to draw route from current location to specified place. 
 If you have sample app please give me a link or please give me some hint about it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want add [MKPolyline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html) to the map using MKMapView's `addOverlay:` function. Then in your MKMapView's delegate you'll want to override the `mapView:viewForOverlay:` and return MKPolylineViews with the settings like color and width of the line to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apple CrumbPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_CrumbPath_h.html).